# Reassign Observable used via Async pipe

Tags: angular

Let's say in my *Component* I have an `Observable` field, which is retrieved via a *Service*, which uses `HttpClient`

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  items$: Observable<readonly Item[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items$ = this.findItems();
  }

  private findItems() {
    return this.service
      .getItems(...)
      .pipe(
        // Other code omitted
        toArray<Item>()
      );
  }
}
```

---

```
<app-items [items]="items$ | async"></app-items>
```

---

Then, when an action is performed inside `MyComponent`, I need to refresh that `items$` list, thus I call the *Service*

```
onButtonPressed() {
  this.items$ = this.findItems();
}
```

---

The questions are, does the `Async` pipe automatically subscribe to the new `Observable`?
Do I need to ask for a `detectChanges()`, considering I'm on the `OnPush` strategy?
And most importantly, is this the right approach?

Comment: No need to use `detectChanges`. the async pipe will detect the changes and update the values.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka this question arises because the new items don't seem to be rendered using the re-assignment, plus `async` pipe. I'll give it another shot trying to look for mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `switchMap` pipe :

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  items$: Observable<readonly Item[]>;

  updater$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items$ = this.updater$
      .pipe(
        switchMap<void, Observable<Items[]>>(() => this.findItems())
      )
  }

  onButtonPressed(){
    this.updater$.next();
  }

  private findItems() {
    return this.service
      .getItems(...)
      .pipe(
        // Other code omitted
        toArray<Item>()
      );
  }
}
```

and still use :

```
<app-items [items]="items$ | async"></app-items>
```

---

`switchMap()` allows you to have a single "never-reassigned" observable (`updater$`) and for each emittance on this stream, it "switches" the emitted value of the observable to send the result of the inner function instead, which should be an observable.

Here, each time you call `updater$.next()`, it "switches" the emitted `void` to the result of the `findItems()` method, which is your items array.

The difference between `switchMap` and `mergeMap` is that `switchMap` takes care of completing and closing the previous emitted observable. If you call `updater$.next()` twice, the second call of `switchMap` will complete the first observable returned by the first call of `findItems()` and replace it by a new call of this method.

Sources:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html
https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, yes, a call to `ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges` is needed if using the `OnPush` change-detection strategy.

```
constructor(
  ...
  private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

onButtonPressed() {
  this.items$ = this.findItems();
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a "nicer" way of doing this, if not by using a second `[Behavior]Subject`.

---

Edit: I noticed re-assigning and calling `detectChanges` can cause flickering.
In the end I went for the `BehaviorSubject` alternative.

```
private readonly items = new BehaviorSubject<readonly Item[]>([]);

constructor(...) {
  items$ = this.items.asObservable(); 
}

...

this.findItems().subscribe(items => this.items.next(items));
```

Thus, no more re-assignment.

Comment: I think I find a way to achieve this without using a subscription, nor `detectChanges()`. Please have a look to my anwser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% sure answer as it is not documented, however we can get some clues from handling `Promise` by `async` pipe in [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```
greeting: Promise<string>|null = null;
  private resolve: Function|null = null;

  constructor() {
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    this.greeting = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
    });
  }
```

Here we can see reassigning Promise must trigger change detection otherwise the code would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing a similar example locally with Angular v12 and i found that the reassignment of a new Observable has indeed triggered a new subscribe of the Asnyc Pipe.

I tested also with Stackblitz (Angular v16) and i came to the same conclusion. (I used a search example instead of clicking a button)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Posts!</h1>
    <input (keyup)="search($event)" />
    <div *ngFor="let product of (posts$ | async)">
    <h5>{{product.title}}</h5>
    <p>{{product.body}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  posts$: Observable<any> | undefined;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.httpClient
      .get<any>('https://dummyjson.com/posts')
      .pipe(map((response) => response.posts));
  }

  search(event: any) {
    this.posts$ = this.httpClient
      .get<any>(`https://dummyjson.com/posts/search?q=${event.target.value}`)
      .pipe(map((response) => response.posts));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Here is the live example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j2n7pq?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score -2):

> does the Async pipe automatically subscribe to the new Observable?

The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

> Do I need to ask for a detectChanges(), considering I'm on the OnPush
>   strategy?

You don't need to.  When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes.

is this the right approach?
I see no harm in it as the subscription will unsubscribed automatically when the component gets destroyed.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question about re-assignment of the field.

Comment: The question is not about new emitted item in the current piped stream ... it is about the async pipe behavior if the observable is reassigned with a new stream.